# Print out all of the parent and child routes in the template for Ember

Tags: ember.js

Suppose I have an Ember route like the following

`myApp/RouteA/RouteB/RouteC`

Is there a way that I could get all the names of different route levels in either my route or controller?

The reason is because I'm trying to write an ember component that dynamically generates breadcrumbs.

Here is a little more specific of an example

[image]

Comment: I would recommend to use one of the [existing addons](https://www.emberobserver.com/?query=breadcrumb). [ember-crumbly](https://github.com/poteto/ember-crumbly) seems to be the de facto standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @jelhan commented a good existing addon, it's straightforward to implement your own should you need to.

Ember has a public [router service](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/RouterService) which can be used to get info about the current route. One such method that would work here is [currentRouteName](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.11/classes/RouterService/properties/currentRoute?anchor=currentRouteName). Imagine the route structure:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.route('blog', function () {
    this.route('post', { path: ':post_id' });
  });
});
```

- `currentRouteName` will return

  - `index` when you visit `/`
  - `about` when you visit `/about`
  - `blog.index` when you visit `/blog`
  - `blog.post` when you visit `/blog/some-post-id`

You can split on the separator to get the different route parts to build up your breadcrumbs. In your breadcrumbs component, simply inject the routerService and use a computed property to get the current breadcrumbs (this will update when app changes routes)

```
import Component from '@ember/components';
import { inject } from '@ember/service';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({
  router: inject(),
  breadcrumbs: computed('router.currentRouteName', function(){
     // build your breadcrumbs however you see fit
  })
})
```